# How to properly target this background image to get parallax effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this image as a background for a "parallax-divider" div, which I wish to stay on the page as it is, but I would like to make the image scroll slower than other content in order to accomplish a parallax effect. I know that I'm targeting something wrong way, but can't figure out how to fix it. Only thing I get is to move the whole div up and down/stretching in a very undesireable way. Any opinions how to fix this?

Here's the Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxOYrQ

```
.section {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parallax-divider {
  background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Cool-Background-Wallpaper-Dekstop.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 200px;
}

<div class="section"></div>

<div class="parallax-divider" id="parlx">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parallax-divider__image">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section"></div>

function parallax() {
  var parlx = document.getElementById('parlx');
  parlx.style.position = "relative";
  parlx.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 8) + 'px';
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: translateY()` instead of top property. Also set parallax elemen to `position: absolute`, `width: 100%` and it wont strech. Like so :

```
translate('+ (-(window.pageYOffset / 8)) + 'px';
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work, could you edit the pen please?